# Bootsrap-Datepicker not able to get date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm using the following jQuery Datepicker and when I try to use JS to get the values I'm either getting "undefined" or "[object Object]".

I'm automatically setting a value to the datepicker and when viewing the page I can see a value.

Here is the code I have. I've tried it with the id being on the wrapping  around the  as well as the id on the actual  but got the same results.

```
<div class="col-md-2 text-left">
    <div class="input-group date">
        <input id="startDatepicker" class="datepicker form-control" type="text" />
        <div class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript I've tried base on the suggestions I've seen in my research.

```
    var start = $('#startdate').datepicker("getDate");
    //var start = $('#startdate').data('datepicker').date;
    //var start = $('#startdate').val();
    //var start = $('#startdate').data('datepicker').date;
    alert(start);
```

Comment: You have the wrong id in your jquery selector.

Comment: Thanks, I guess with all the copy and paste back and forth I got them switched.

Comment: I changed my script to "var start = $('#startDatepicker').datepicker("getDate");" but that still returns [object Object]. Anyone if this if this is the script to get the values out of the input? Or is there additional script I need to add to it to pull the value out of the object?

Comment: Once I made the change in my previous post I now see the following in my console log. "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" but that might be the alert(start) causing that message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'ts probably because your input is empty.

[check this out(JSFiddle) :](https://jsfiddle.net/xpb9s4ef/1/)

```
 <input id="startDatepicker" class="datepicker form-control" type="text" value="05/09/2016" />
```

and

```
 $('#startDatepicker').datepicker();
 $('#getdate').on('click', function() {
    var st = $('#startDatepicker').datepicker('getDate');
    alert(st)
    console.log(st);
});
```